# callback URL after succesfull Video post trough Facebook API graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm starting to get my Facebook integration working on my own app but I'm still strugling with one part:

create a callback URL of redirect URL after a successful video post on my facebook wall trough:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.9/me/videos?source={{video_source}}&access_token={{access_token}}="POST">
<input name="file" type="file" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Does anyone know how to do this. So after a successfull upload redirect to a page in my app.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: To bad. Also not trough another way of coding? Like with javascript or something like that?

Comment: Well if that endpoint is CORS-enabled, you could use AJAX to make the upload ... then you can check the actual API response, and redirect elsewhere based on that ...